# How to escape string in a command argument

Tags: latex, pdflatex, miktex

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{some_thing}
foo
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

When compiling with Miktex/pdflatex, I get

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
l.8 \begin{minted}{some_thing}
```

So far, I have figured out that the underscore in `some_thing` is the problem. This is only a problem when I add the `syntax` package. Note that the best case here is still an error: `Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output;`. The argument in question is supposed to point to a file. The example is really contrived, sorry.

So I guess I need to escape the underscore somehow? Just going `some\_thing` gives me the same error. I guess command arguments are somehow different. What can I do here?

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302168

> `\#` is a `\chardef` token which typesets a `#` but doesn't expand to a `#` in filenames etc

The post uses the command `\string` to escape a `#`.

That explains why `\_` doesn't do anything in that place. In my case, `\begin{minted}{some\string_thing}` works just fine.

I tried `\begin{minted}{\string{some_thing}}` because that would be more readable IMO, but that doesn't work. I guess that's not how `\string` works? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯